# Android Emulator Rendering Issue

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running Android Emulator Version 28.0.22 on Windows 1809 (This problem was there in older versions too). There are some rendering issues in the emulator as can be seen in the attached image. I can't see any font's and sometimes imageviews in any applications.

Android versions previous to API 28 are working properly. But all Android Pie images (X86, X86_64, Google Play edition) all are having the same issue.

Gpu - GTX 1050 and Integrated Graphics: Intel HD 630. Tried force using integrated graphics as well as GPU. No Change.

Emulator config.ini is attached below.

Can anyone help me on this?

[image: Error Screenshot 1] [image: Error Screenshot 2]

Following is the AVD Configuration (config.ini)

```
AvdId=Nexus_6P_API_28
PlayStore.enabled=false
abi.type=x86
avd.ini.displayname=Nexus 6P API 28
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
disk.dataPartition.size=2G
fastboot.chosenSnapshotFile=
fastboot.forceChosenSnapshotBoot=no
fastboot.forceColdBoot=no
fastboot.forceFastBoot=yes
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.arc=false
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=virtualscene
hw.camera.front=emulated
hw.cpu.arch=x86
hw.cpu.ncore=4
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:984dbf66b1aaafcdb7e89573ffb74b46
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus 6P
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.gpu.mode=auto
hw.initialOrientation=Portrait
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=560
hw.lcd.height=2560
hw.lcd.width=1440
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=3500
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no
image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-28\google_apis\x86\
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
sdcard.size=1G
showDeviceFrame=yes
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=nexus_5
skin.path=F:\Program Files\Android\Sdk\skins\nexus_5
tag.display=Google APIs
tag.id=google_apis
vm.heapSize=1024
hw.mainKeys=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
```

Comment: In Emulator's Settings > Advanced, set OpenGL ES to Compatibility.

Comment: @DamnVegetables Thanks. It worked. You may post the comment as answer since it fixed it for me.